# how to click on ribbon button using javascript?

Tags: 2013

I want to trigger click for a ribbon button using Javascript. I used click() hence it did not triggered the event.

```
$("#my.Ribbon.customTab.ThiscustomGroup.bigbutton-Large").click();
```

Comment: What exactly do you need this for? For automated testing? Or do you just need to call a ribbon action?

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev its linked to my question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116270/application-page-sometime-look-dim , issue is that when i click on ribbon button form appears ok all the time but when i cick on button on the page i added using jslink. my application page looks dim as explained in my other question

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with plain js,

```
document.getElementById("Ribbon.Documents.EditCheckout.CheckIn-Medium").click();
```

for some reason using JQuery `.trigger('click')` or `.click()` doesn't trigger the buttons

BTW

you have to use 2 backward slashes to match ids with dots (in case you want to use JQuery for something else)

e.g.

```
//no match
$("#Ribbon.Documents.EditCheckout.CheckIn-Medium")

//match
$("#Ribbon\\.Documents\\.EditCheckout\\.CheckIn-Medium")
```

[How to select html nodes by ID with jquery when the id contains a dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot)

Answer (score 1):

On SharePoint 2013, click the browse button:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ms-cui-tt-span")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function called "UploadAttachment()". For example you can use something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Attach File" onclick="javascript:UploadAttachment()" />
```